# How can I Upload file like object to nextcloud with python using easywebdav

Tags: python, webdav, os.path, owncloud

**I want to export the wallpapers directly to my nextcloud except that it does not work knowing that I am handling an object in python**

```
      import easywebdav
      from wallhaven.api import Wallhaven
    #Settings Webdav
    webdav = easywebdav.connect('192.168.1.40', username='Uri3l', password='mypassword', protocol='http', port=80, verify_ssl=False)

Mydir = webdav.cd("Wallhaven")
results = wallhaven.search()
  

  
  for wallpaper in results.data:
    wallpaper.save(os.path.dirname(Mydir))
  
download()
```

**I get this error like os.PathLike object when I run the code**

```
File "/home/dark/Dev/Bot/WallHaven-Bot/Bot_with_api.py", line 39, in download
    wallpaper.save(os.path.dirname(Mydir))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 152, in dirname
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
~/Dev ᐅ
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, you are using two incompatible interfaces. Even if the `cd` function would return a path (by definition returns nothing which is the same as `None`) the wallhaven module would download it somewhere to your local computer instead of webdav. The easiest way to find this out is to look for proper method documentation like [Wallhaven.save](https://github.com/lucasshiva/wallhaven/blob/444a04d3e574579b08cf1bc0fa7879b41621d916/wallhaven/models/api.py#L166)

You can achieve what you want, by using your computer as temporary storage for both modules.

```py
import os
import easywebdav
from wallhaven.api import Wallhaven
import tempfile
# Settings Webdav


webdav = easywebdav.connect('192.168.1.40', username='Uri3l', password='mypassword', protocol='http', port=80,
                            verify_ssl=False)

webdav.cd("Wallhaven")
results = wallhaven.search()

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as td:
    for wallpaper in results.data:
        filename = f"wallhaven-{wallpaper.id}{wallpaper.extension}"  # from the Wallpapers save function
        wallpaper.save(td)
        webdav.upload(os.path.join(td, filename), filename)  # should upload to webdav cwd ?? cant test it
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure to define correctly the variable Mydir before the execution, according to the error the variable Mydir is not defined because it is of type "Nonetype".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).